# SAML auth fails in WebIDE Full-Stack in "Run-As" mode

Tags: authentication, saml, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

On SAP Web IDE Multi-Cloud version, when right clicking and going to Run > Run as > Web Application or SAP Fiori Launchpad Sandbox it gets to the SAML authentication and that stops on a white screen, with no errors in the console log.

I've tried this on custom apps I've created and also a new SAPUI5 app from template, nothing works. It only works if I deploy it to the SAP Cloud Platform then register it to my personal Fiori Launchpad.

I've tried the exact same in the standard SAP Web IDE version (non- Multi-Cloud version) and it works.

If anyone knows the solution to this, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be working fine on our side.
Which browser are you using?
There have been issues with several Chrome extensions blocking the runtime.
Maybe you can try different browsers?
Please report if the issue still exists.

Please also check your Trust configuration 
as seen in Step 5) [here](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/webide-multi-cloud.html) 
and as seen in the comments section [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/11/announcing-general-availability-of-sap-web-ide-multicloud-version)

Comment: Chrome, but have also tried in IE. My colleagues version works fine in both versions of the Web IDE. Principal Propagation was already enabled. I've commented on the link to see if my credentials can be checked.

Comment: Can you logon on your colleagues computer with your UserID and see if it works from there, with his browser and your UserID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. Turns out the destinations 'webide_di' & 'webide_di_s2s' should be created automatically when you enable the SAP Web IDE Multi Cloud Version service, but in my case they were not. Once I added them manually, it started working.